# Creating an algorithm to find all possible clusters in java

Tags: java, dynamic, cluster-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to find all possible clusters of [A0....An-1] into k non-empty clusters with any n in java for example:

`A=[1,2,3,4] , n = 4 , k = 3` would return these 3 possible cluster options:

```
[1][2][3,4]
[1][2,3][4]
[1,2][3][4]
```

Any help with this at all would be greatly appreciated!! this stuff is certainly not my strong point with programming and is currently driving me crazy!

Comment: Try to compute the number of results first. This may get you into the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recursion for this task.
**Code**

```
private static void getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k, int idx, Set<Integer> current,List<Set<Integer>> solution) {
    //successful stop clause
    if (current.size() == k) {
        solution.add(new HashSet<>(current));
        return;
    }
    //unseccessful stop clause
    if (idx == superSet.size()) return;
    Integer x = superSet.get(idx);
    current.add(x);
    //"guess" x is in the subset
    getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
    current.remove(x);
    //"guess" x is not in the subset
    getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
}

public static List<Set<Integer>> getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k) {
    List<Set<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    getSubsets(superSet, k, 0, new HashSet<Integer>(), res);
    return res;
}
```

**Function**

```
List<Integer> superSet = new ArrayList<>();
superSet.add(1);
superSet.add(2);
superSet.add(3);
superSet.add(4);
System.out.println(getSubsets(superSet,2));
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement in c++ then:

```
#include<iostream>
   #include<cstdio>
   #include<vector>
   using namespace std;
   vector<int> v;
   vector<vector<int> > result;

  void subset(int arr[],int k,int n,int idx){
  if(idx==n)
 return;

if(k==1){
    for(int i=idx;i<n;i++)
     {
        v.push_back(arr[i]);
        result.push_back(v);
        v.pop_back();
     }
}

 for(int j=idx;j<n;j++) {
  v.push_back(arr[j]);
  subset(arr,k-1,n,j+1);
  v.pop_back();
  }
 }

int main(){
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int k = 4;
int n =sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
subset(arr,k,n,0);

for(int i = 0;i<result.size();i++)
 { 
  for(int j = 0;j<result[i].size();j++)
   {
     cout << result[i][j] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
 }
}
```